# Mod-editing a chat messages loses the "reply" button

Tags: bug, chat, moderator-tools

When editing another user's message in chat (which is rare, but doesn't matter :p), the "reply to this message" icon is gone afterwards.

Comment: It also makes the chat message show up under your username in the sidebar.

Comment: @Mr.PeanutMonopolyMcManish Err, what? Got a screenshot?

Comment: @AnnaLear http://i.stack.imgur.com/zvFY9.png vs http://i.stack.imgur.com/yiUJr.png

Comment: @Mr.PeanutMonopolyMcManish Huh. I never noticed that.

Comment: @AnnaLear I think we noticed it during the Android town hall chat, I was helping Grace edit message replies into messages and strange stuff kept happening

Comment: and its [tag:status-as-it-is]...

Answer (score 2):

Basically, when a chat message is *edited*, the userid/username sent through the websocket is that of the editor, making the message seemingly owned by the editor. This removes the reply option and puts the message under the editor's username in the sidebar.

This can be fixed by making the user details sent through on the server side that of the owner, not the editor.